# Placing pdf documents into LaTeX

Tags: pdfpages, include

I want to include several pdf documents along my main LaTeX text, but I encountered an obstacle. When I compile, the pdf appears perfectly, but it is always placed in the next page, so there is an empty page with the title, and then the pdf shows up. I´ve tried to scale it, but no matter how small it is, it always appears in a new page.

Here is some of the packages related I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
```

And this is the command for the pdf:

```
\includepdf[pages=-, scale=1, pagecommand={}]{Examen Final.pdf}
```

An example of how it looks:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "an empty page with the title"?  What title is this?  Where does it come from?

Comment: `\includepdf` inserts _pages_ you can not put them inside a page of the main document. If the pdf you are inserting is a single page you can insert it with `\includegraphics` then it cca be part of a lartger page.

Comment: And if the pdf is larger than one page, is there a solution or I should take pics of each page and insert them via `\includegraphics`? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: you can insert one scaled page at a time using includegraphics[page=2]{..}  repeated for each page number but are you sure you want to do this? You want to scale all the included pages by the same amount and if you scale to fit a heading on the first page they will all be too small for the surrounding document.